# jQuery animate function won't get to the desired destination value when duration is very small, what to do?

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/zaphn7of/1/

```
var DUR = 1000;
var destination = 10;
$({someValue: 0}).animate({
  someValue: destination
}, {
  duration: DUR,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function() {
    var t = $('#output').text();
    $('#output').text(t + '\n' + Math.ceil(this.someValue));
  },
  complete: function() {}
});
```

In this case, if you change the `DUR` to 10 or 100, it will never reaches the destination "10".

Is there anyway to let it reach the destination but keep the duration very small?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` , with `duration` interval set to `DUR` divided by `destination`

```js
var DUR = 10;
var destination = 100;
var props = {
  someValue: 0
};
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var interval = null;
var fx = function fx() {
  // increment `props` : `this` `someValue` property
  this.someValue += 1;
  // append `someValue` to `output` `textContent`
  output.textContent += "\n" + this.someValue;
}

interval = setInterval(function() {
  // if `props`.someValue` is less than `destination`,
  // call `fx`
  if (props.someValue < destination) {
    // call `fx` with `this` set to `props` object
    fx.call(props)
  } else {
    // clear `interval`
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    console.log(props)
  }
}, DUR / destination);
```

```html
<pre id="output">
  
</pre>
```

jsfiddle `DUR` set to `100` https://jsfiddle.net/zaphn7of/3/ , `DUR` set to `3000` https://jsfiddle.net/zaphn7of/4/

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to "fix" jQuery's animate? Because sometimes I may change the destination value and easing function so that it's quite hard to make it work with `setinterval`.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo _"Thanks but is there any way to "fix" jQuery's animate? Because sometimes I may change the destination value and easing function so that it's quite hard to make it work with setinterval"_ You could use recursion to animate the properties incrementally; from `0` to `1` , `1` to `2` up until `destination` is reached, still including `DUR / destination` at `duration` of `.animate()` https://jsfiddle.net/zaphn7of/5/